# How to turn an Array into an Object. Elements of the Array should be Keys and the Values should be output from the Callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, callback, key-value

I am trying to code to the function **arrToObj** to achieve the desired console logs. **arrToObj** should return an object that has elements from the passed-in array as keys, and the outputs from the callback (when those elements are passed in) as the corresponding values.

Here is the code I am given...

```
function arrToObj(array, callback) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
 const arrOfStrings = ['beer', 'glue'];
 const capitalize = str => str.toUpperCase();
 console.log(arrToObj(arrToObj(arrOfStrings, capitalize)); // should log: { beer: 'BEER', glue: 'GLUE' }
```

I'm not sure where to start. Hints or solutions are both welcome. Thank you for your time!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Or in other words... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for` loop would already be enough to get the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use reduce

```js
function arrToObj(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce((acc, next) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [next]: callback(next),
    };
  }, {})
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
const arrOfStrings = ['beer', 'glue'];
const capitalize = str => str.toUpperCase();
console.log(arrToObj(arrOfStrings, capitalize)); // should log: { beer: 'BEER', glue: 'GLUE' }
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get why this doesn't return two separate objects because it is within the reduce method. Also why are you using the rest operator on ...acc ? Wouldn't removing ...acc still return the proper output? Do you know any good resources for learning and understanding reduce?

Comment: the acc is the object. It is empty when reducer starts. the spread operator just ads a new set of key-value pair to whatever is already in the acc object. If you remove the spread operator it will only return an object with a single key/value pair for the last element of the array. There are many resources to learn reduce. I don't have any at hand. But it is worth learning it as it can accomplish many things.